# Best-practices for versioning of Flex applications

Tags: apache-flex, versioning

Can anyone recommend a way to do versioning in Flex applications?

Should I embed a version string somewhere in the swf?

Should the version be part of the URL?

Should it be in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=9503) should be of help to get started.